# Colorbox not working with Pinterest

Tags: colorbox, pinterest

I've been using the most updated version of colorbox with an RSS feed from various web site..and it works well...but it won't work with Pinterest..it just goes blank.  Here is where the rss feed is from ReadWriteWeb (and works, as it does with CNN and tons of other rss feeds):

http://www.allenweiss.com/test

Here it is with a pinterest feed:

http://www.allenweiss.com/test

Any ideas why it isn't working with Pinterest?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you omitted the pinterest example.

If you are displaying the pinterest links the same way you are displaying the links from CNN, then it could be an issue with pinterest frame-busting.  I'm not sure if pinterest prohibits iframing of their pages or not, but some sites certainly do.

Comment: right...I read yesterday that Pinterest disallows web sites from iframing their content..so much for the social web.